# ¿Se puede "rescatar" el valor anterior de una variable que cambió?

Tags: python

Estaba haciendo un mini juego con pygame, y dentro del bucle del juego las variables de posición de una figura cambian (o sea avanza), y quiero que otra figura imite exactamente sus movimientos como "persiguiéndola" pegada a la otra, y pensé que podía hacer esto asignándole a las variables de posición de la segunda figura el número que anteriormente había tenido la variable de posición de la primera, pero no sé como hacer esto. Sería muy agradable alguna ayuda.

Comment: Por qué no lo asignas a otra variable? Hay formas de conseguir lo que buscas pero para esa casuística lo veo quizá demasiado rebuscado :/

Comment: Qué tal si declaras dos variables?

Comment: @IvanSanczewski tal vez necesitarías otra mas para definir la dirección

Comment: Hola, Bienvenid@ al Sitio, veo que eres nuev@ te recomendaría hacer el [tour] para que conozcas mejor el sitio, He mirado tu post y te comento lo siguiente:, Puedes leer este Articulo [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, Me parece que a tu POST le falta un [example]. Saludos

Comment: No, al menos tal como lo planteas. La memoria es volátil, cuando modificaste el valor de un variable perdiste el anterior, si quieres el estado anterior deberás mantenerlo en  otra variable o manejar algún tipo de colección u objeto que te  permita mantener los n estados de tu variable. Si pudieras ser un poco más concreto en tu pregunta, incluso añadiendo algo de código  de ejemplo, tal vez podríamos darte alguna respuesta útil.

Comment: Lo cierto es que en determinados casos sí es posible recuperar el dato anterior de una variable que ha sido modificada:

Solo hay que aplicar una operación binaria `xor` sobre el dato antiguo con el dato nuevo, de modo que al repetir esta operación una segunda vez sobre el valor actual de la variable se obtiene el dato más antiguo...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No hay forma de recuperar el valor previo de una variable, pero hay muchas formas de ir guardando los valores que haya tomado una variable en algún tipo de estructura de datos para luego recuperar esos valores de esa estructura más adelante.

La estructura de datos más directa para esto podría ser una lista. El jugador al moverse va metiendo datos en esa lista. Posteriormente puedes sacar de ella esos datos para recrear el movimiento de quien le sigue.

No obstante Python proporciona una clase especializada en ese tipo de operaciones, que puede hacer aún más sencilla la programación. Se trata de una **cola** (`queue`). Estos objetos pueden ir guardando datos haciendo sobre ellos la operación `.put()` y más tarde recuperarlos en el mismo orden en que se metieron haciendo la operación `.get()`. Además dan métodos auxiliares como `.empty()` que devuelve un booleano para saber si la cola está vacía (pues si intentas un `.get()` y no hay más datos, el proceso se bloquearía), o `.qsize()` que te dice cuántos datos hay metidos en la cola.

Un ejemplo muy sencillo. El siguiente bucle va generando números seguidos y los mete en una cola como que fueran las acciones de un hipotético jugador. El mismo bucle también va sacando valores de la cola, pero sólo cuando ésta tenga más de dos elementos. De ese modo el "follower" del jugador va tres pasos por detrás.

```py
import queue

q = queue.Queue()

for i in range(10):
  if q.qsize()>2:
    follower = q.get()
    print("  Follower:", follower)
  print("Player:", i)
  q.put(i)
```

Al ejecutar este bucle el resultado es:

```html
Player: 0
Player: 1
Player: 2
  Follower: 0
Player: 3
  Follower: 1
Player: 4
  Follower: 2
Player: 5
  Follower: 3
Player: 6
  Follower: 4
Player: 7
  Follower: 5
Player: 8
  Follower: 6
Player: 9
```

Observa que tal como está hecho este ejemplo cuando el bucle termina la cola aún tiene 3 elementos que no se han sacado de ella. Puedes eliminarlos con `q.queue.clear()`

Naturalmente lo que guardes en la cola puede ser de cualquier tipo. En este ejemplo he usado enteros para simplificar, pero en tu caso posiblemente quieras guardar tuplas de valores que representen las coordenadas del jugador. Sería igual de sencillo. Esto para meterlas:

```
q.put((x,y))
```

y esto para sacarlas:

```
x, y = q.get()
```

Puedes extender la idea para guardar una tupla con más elementos (hacia dónde mira, por ejemplo), o guardar objetos con sus propiedades, etc.

Answer (score -1):

Sin saber mucho de tu código puedes añadir una lista de tuplas que recoja las variables y que a cada ciertas iteraciones elimine las anteriores ya utilizadas, otra el eje x y otra el eje y :

```
x,y=100,100
listacoord=[]
#tu bucle del juego
while True:
   listacoord.append((x,y))
   if len(listacoord)==100:
       sprite2=listacoord[0]
       listacoord.remove(listacoord[0])
```

De todas maneras añade un poco de código.
Creo que no se pueden recuperar información de variables cambiadas

A parte de la anterior solución también puedes crear un threading y mover el segundo sprite con retardo.

```
import threading 
import time

x2,y2=None
def funtion():
   global x2, y2
   while True:
       x2=x
       y2=y 
       time.sleep(0.5)
       #actualizar x2 y y2 a tu sprite 
       #como no se como lo tendrás no lo puedo hacer yo
   



t=threading.thread(target=funtion)
t.start()
while True:
   #tu juego
```

Creo que esta solución es mejor que la anterior